# How do I pull a specified value out of a php switch?

Tags: php, variables, switch-statement

I'm working on this assignment where we need to create a little web app to have someone order what they want on a sandwich, and then put it in simpler terms for whoever gets the order to make the sandwich.

The size of the sandwich needs to be a PHP switch. The three sizes (small, medium, and large) refer to how many slices of meat are on the sandwich (as indicated by "slices").

The switch is as follows:
HTML

```
Size
<select name="size">
<option value="small">Small</option>
<option value="medium">Medium</option>
<option value="large">Large</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
$size=$_POST['size'];

switch ($size) {
case "small":
    slices=2;
    break;
case "medium":
    slices=4;
    break;
case "large":
    slices=6;
    break;
}

$output2= slices "slices of $meattype";

echo $output2;
```

Except, it's not working. What's the right way to get the right value of slices into the html rendering based on what the user selects?

Comment: Do you have a form? Did you submit that form or you trying to run the PHP script on the same site?

Comment: It's a form that leads to a php script on the same website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this. PHP variables need to begin with $

```
$size=$_POST['size'];

switch ($size) {
case "small":
    $slices=2;
    break;
case "medium":
    $slices=4;
    break;
case "large":
    $slices=6;
    break;
}

$output2= $slices." slices of ".$meattype;

echo $output2;
```

Comment: You should also note that OP was missing the concatenation operators in the third-last line.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that as soon as I hit submit. :)

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
$output2= slices "slices of $meattype";
```

you interpolate the variable `$meattype` but you haven't defined the variable anywhere.

In your switch it looks like you are trying to assign values to the variable `slices` but PHP variables must begin with `$`.

Finally when you say:

```
$output2= slices "slices of $meattype";
```

Putting the word slices before the string literal here isn't syntactically valid in php.  I'm not sure what you meant by it but you want probably want to remove it.

Comment: Fair enough. The $meattype area of the form works. It just selects between ham and turkey. I'm trying to say "numberofslicesyouwant of $meattype". I just don't know the syntax for it.

Comment: @Chris Rasco's answer below should do it.

Answer (score 0):

just have a glance, i dont know if you are missing the dollar signs and the dot signs for concatenating strings.

is the following what you need?
P.S. double quoted strings will be automatically parsed by PHP, so dollars sign variable in that works.

```
$size=$_POST['size'];

switch ($size) {
case "small":
    $slices=2;
    break;
case "medium":
    $slices=4;
    break;
case "large":
    $slices=6;
    break;
}

$output2= $slices . "slices of $meattype";

echo $output2;
```

By the way, you will need a valid form, too. (Assumes the php you written above is blablalba.php)

```
<form action='blablabla.php'>
Size
   <select name="size">
      <option value="small">Small</option>
      <option value="medium">Medium</option>
      <option value="large">Large</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Comment: $meattype is nowhere defined.

Comment: I assumes he is posting a "cut version" of his PHP, because he dont have <?php and ?> neither, if you insist on that.